# Java - setVisible(true)

Tags: java, swing

I made a simple JDialog which contains a label and a button, its basically an equivalent of information dialog. So in the dialog, there is a method display()  in which I called setVisible(true)  five times.

From my knowledge, when this display method is called it should only display the dialog once but it actually created 5 dialogs, Why did it create 5 dialogs?

Edit1: My problem is more similar to this :

```
import java.awt.event.*;import java.awt.*;import javax.swing.*;
class Demo implements ActionListener
{
JFrame f;
JButton b;  
DisplayDialog dialog;
public Demo() 
{
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(200,200);

    b = new JButton("Click me");

    f.add(b);
    dialog = new DisplayDialog();

    b.addActionListener(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object o = e.getSource();

    if(o==b)
    {
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello");
        dialog.display("Hello5");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Demo d = new Demo();
}

class DisplayDialog implements ActionListener
{
        JDialog dg;
        JLabel l;
        JButton b;
        Font myfont;

        public DisplayDialog()
        {
            dg = new JDialog(f,"Alert!",true);
            dg.setSize(300,150);
            l = new JLabel("Message");
            b = new JButton("OK");

            myfont = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,12);
            l.setFont(myfont);

            dg.add(l);
            dg.add(b,"South");

            dg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

            b.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object o = e.getSource();
            if(o==b)
            {
                dg.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        public void display(String str)
        {
            l.setText(str);
            dg.setVisible(true);

        }
  } 
}
```

Edit2 : Now a situation like this is occurring in my program and rather than displaying the dialog 5 times, I want it to display the last one, what can i do to achieve this?

Comment: And where do you call `display(String str)` ??

Comment: @Antoniossss Just create an object and call it with string of your choice.

In my program, I just added a new JMenuItem and display(String str) is called whenever it is clicked.

Comment: But it is your example that does not work so provide your code expecialy that this depends of `f` variable (probably JFrame) so who knows hat you could break over there.

Comment: Why do you call `setVisible()` five times? What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so basicly it is **not showing 5 times at once** only it is shown **5 times in a row**.

`JDialog.setVisible(true)` is a blocking operation and blocks until dialog is closed.

So one dialog pops up and app blocks on `setVisible(true)` when you close it, another `serVisible(true)` is invoked and so on.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying. Now I am stuck in situation more similar to this :

Comment: @KaranNagpal you did not paste the link. Anyway, as this fullfils your question, mark it as accepted and post another one. Ill try to help over there.

Comment: i edited the question which better explains my situation @Antoniossss

Answer (score 0):

You only create one dialog instance with

```
dg = new JDialog(f,"Alert!",true);
```

Then you display this same dialog five times with the multiple calls to `setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

As to your edit: What is your problem then?

Change

```
if (o == b) {
    dialog.display("Hello");
    dialog.display("Hello");
    dialog.display("Hello");
    dialog.display("Hello");
    dialog.display("Hello5");
}
```

to

```
    if (o == b) {
        dialog.display("Hello");
    }
```

Comment: In my main program, there are 4 internal frames each containing this info dialog 4+ times. These internal frames are interrelated so sometimes a situation occurs  in which this function gets called 8+ times . So I want it to appear only once rather than 8 dialog boxes. @Antoniossss

Comment: Either post the code that actually reflects what is happening in your situation and to whitch you are seeking solution, or quit searching for help here. The solution for the problem you have provided (even with Demo code!) Is to not to call `display` multiple times one by one. What does this exampla has to do with your app, nobody knows, and I think that you dont know that as well. You only think that this is the same as your problem but for 99% it is not.

Comment: The application code is of 1000 lines and that situation occurs at a very specific input.
I just need to know what should do I so that whenever display(String str) is called, if there a dialog already opened, it gets closed.

Comment: `if(dialog.isVisible) dialog.setVisible(false)` ?? This is not what you have asked in the question. Again, accept and post new, more precise question.

Comment: Changed the method to this 
       public void display(String str)
   {
    if(dg.isVisible())
     dg.setVisible(false);
    l.setText(str);
    dg.setVisible(true);
    
   }

but still 5 Dialogs appear

Comment: Accept and ask new question.